# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función javascript usando jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Hola estoy haciendo un ejemplo sencillo en la plataforma `jsfiddle` relacionado con javascript. El ejemplo que estaba probando es el siguiente:

https://jsfiddle.net/on0sokue/

El problema es a pesar de haber creado correctamente mi html y luego poner la función en el javascript. Cuando pulso el botón no me cambia el texto del párrafo.

Mi pregunta:

¿Qué modificación debo hacer para que cuando se pulse el botón me cambie el texto de la etiqueta párrafo usando la plataforma jsfiddle?

Es un ejemplo muy básico porque recién empecé a aprender javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tiene configurado que el código `JavaScript` se ejecute en el `onload`, esto provoca que la función `myFunction` no sea una función global y si miras en la consola podrás ver que dice:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Solución:

Debes seleccionar la opción `No wrap - in <head>` o `No wrap - in <body>`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]